# Wrong password when log in - Bcrypt

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am making a login route with `mongoose` and `express`. When I create an account, the password is hashed by `bcrypt`. When I log in, I need to compare them. So here is my try :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "L'e-mail est requis"],
      unique: true
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Le mot de passe est requis"]
    },
    firstname: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Le prénom est requis"]
    },
    lastname: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Le nom est requis"]
    }
  },
  { collection: "users" }
);

UserSchema.pre("save", async function(next) {
  const user = this;
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  const hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
  user.password = hash;
  next();
});

UserSchema.methods.isValidPassword = async function(password) {
  const user = this;
  const compare = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

  return compare;
};

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

The problem is, my route returns "Wrong password".
Here is the controller :

```
module.exports.signIn = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email });

  if (!user) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: "email not found."
    });
  }
  if (user.password !== password) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: "wrong password."
    });
  }

  res.status(200).json({
    message: "User signed in."
  });
};
```

It is like my request doesn't go by `UserSchema.methods.isValidPassword`. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block:

```
 if (user.password !== password) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: "wrong password."
    });
  }
```

just compare the password in the request with the **hash** password stored in your database. The condition is true so you have the message "wrong password".

You need to call the method `isValidPassword` explicitly.

```
 const isValidPassword = await user.isValidPassword(password);
 if (!isValidPassword) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: "wrong password."
    });
  }
```

---

*Quick side note*: You **shouldn't** have 2 different messages for email not found and the wrong password. This allows users to know if the email exists and execute a [brute force attack](https://owasp.org/www-community/controls/Blocking_Brute_Force_Attacks#:%7E:text=A%20brute%2Dforce%20attack%20is,for%20a%20brute%2Dforce%20attack.). I suggest something like "Email or password is incorrect" instead.